# "Red alert" animation effect with Quartz 2D or CALayer animation?

Tags: ios, animation, calayer, quartz-2d

I am new to animations and I just can not find data on how to create an alert light (simple red alert light that flickers).

I know how to animate CALayer and the basics of Quartz 2D, I am just looking for a tutorial or direction on how to achieve back light effect?

Thanks
Shani

Comment: Two images both assigned to an UIImageView with an animation delay setup. (UIImageView animationImages, UIImageView animationDuration, UIImageView animationRepeatCount)

Comment: you mean to switch between them with alpha animation ?

Comment: No, UIImageView has animation capabilities - you may assign multiple images to it and animate through them.

Answer (score 0):

Very hacky code (works but try not using it in production):

```
self.uiView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

CABasicAnimation* selectionAnimation1 = [CABasicAnimation 
                                        animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];

selectionAnimation1.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

selectionAnimation1.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
selectionAnimation1.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];

selectionAnimation1.duration = 0.10;
selectionAnimation1.repeatCount = 20;

[self.uiView1.layer addAnimation:selectionAnimation1
                       forKey:@"opacity"];


self.uiView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

CABasicAnimation* selectionAnimation2 = [CABasicAnimation 
                                        animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];

selectionAnimation2.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

selectionAnimation2.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
selectionAnimation2.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];

selectionAnimation2.duration = 0.10;
selectionAnimation2.repeatCount = 20;

[self.uiView2.layer addAnimation:selectionAnimation2
                          forKey:@"opacity"];
```

uiView1 & uiView2 completely overlap each other. You can replace the two uiView's with two UIImageView's, with one having an image of light turned on (red) and one with light turned off (black/gray). In which case background color change will be redundant.